# Log all outgoing mail created by php

Tags: linux, php, email, vulnerabilities

I have Debian Linux server which serves several PHP sites. Today I received mail from Datacenter where they say my server is sending spam and attached spam message. This was really message from my server and I managed to find it in exim4 mainlog.
Question: how to identify where is the vulnerability in PHP code and which site (i have 3) send this mail?
I've chrooted one site already and disabled php mail and all exec,system etc. functions for it but i'm not sure taht it is site sending mail.
Any way to log message body for all outgoing mail?

Comment: You are sure is a problem with PHP and not with your apache proxy ?

Comment: 100% php. I can see headers in message indicating that it was PHP who send this message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write & configure a wrapper around sendmail that does more logging

in php.ini:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

change to:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

Or in your php code, you could write your own mail function that acts as a wrapper around php mail that does the logging. Remember to validate all input.

Comment: OK. But what is the format of the wrapper? Any example (in any language in any form)?

Comment: Suggest you do the 2nd option, if you are running php sites you should be able to write it.

Comment: Look like it is what i need http://www.iezzi.ch/archives/217

Comment: yes, that looks good